# Uuid on pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying execute laravel migration to create pivot table. I've two models which are defined in relation many to many. Below is method to migration

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('api_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('api_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('api_id')->references('id')->on('apis')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->uuid('user_uid')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_uid')->references('uid')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

After execute php artisan migrate , I received sql error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) def' at line 1 (SQL: create table `api_user` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `api_id` int unsigned not null, `user_uid` char(36) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

Uuid is storing as varch in DB. Perhaps varchart cannot set as unsigned attribute. Is anothoer way to create pivot table from migration except Laravel-5-Generators-Extended.?

Comment: `uuid` is a `char` column, so it cannot be unsigned.

Comment: i know, but is another way to create pivot table using uuid

Comment: This is a fine way to create it, just remove the `unsigned` portion of the `uuid` column creation. `Unsigned` just means that the range of numbers shift to start at 0 instead of having 0 in the middle of the range.

Comment: remove unsigned

Comment: after removed usigned i received  `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `api_user` add constraint `api_user_user_uid_foreign` foreign key (`user_uid`) references `users` (`uid`) on delete cascade)`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did UUID's:

Create an extend Blueprint

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class ExtendedBlueprint extends BluePrint{

    /**
     * Create a new uuid column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function binary_uuid($column)
    {
        return $this->addColumn('buuid', $column);

    }
}
```

Extend the grammar for all the languages you intend to support

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar;
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;


class MysqlExtendedGrammar extends MySqlGrammar 
{


    protected function typeBuuid(Fluent $column)
    {
        return "varbinary(16)";
    }

}

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\PostgresGrammar;
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;

class PostgesExtendedGrammar extends PostgresGrammar 
{


    protected function typeBuuid(Fluent $column)
    {
        return "uuid";
    }
}

use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\SQLiteGrammar;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class SqlLiteExtendedGrammar extends SQLiteGrammar 
{

    protected function typeBuuid(Fluent $column)
    {
        return "blob";
    }
}

use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar;
class SqlServerExtendedGrammar extends SqlServerGrammar 
{


    protected function typeBuuid(Fluent $column)
    {
        return "uniqueidentifer";
    }
}
```

Then create a a schema provider

```
use Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;
use Tschallacka\PageManager\Support\BluePrint\ExtendedBlueprint;
use Db;
use Event;

/**
 * Not so eloquent ;-)
 * @author tschallacka
 *
 */
class Stutter {

    private  $transforms = [
            'mysql'     => 'Tschallacka\PageManager\Support\Grammar\MysqlExtendedGrammar',
            'postgres'  => 'Tschallacka\PageManager\Support\Grammar\PostgesExtendedGrammar',
            'sqlite'    => 'Tschallacka\PageManager\Support\Grammar\SqlLiteExtendedGrammar',
            'sqlsrv'    => 'Tschallacka\PageManager\Support\Grammar\SqlServerExtendedGrammar',
    ];

    /**
     * Set the grammar to a certain driver
     * @param string $driver mysql, postgres, sqlite, sqlsrv, something else
     * @param string $grammar Your extended grammar class '\Foo\Bar\MysqlExtendedGrammar'
     */
    public function setGrammar($driver, $grammar) 
    {
        $this->transforms[$driver] = $grammar;  
    }

    public function getGrammar($driver) {
        if(array_key_exists($driver, $this->transforms)) {
            return $this->transforms[$driver];
        }
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("Unsupported database driver $driver\n"
                ."Please attach a listener to event tschallacka.get.binary_uuid.grammars\n"
                ."and provide an extended grammar for for generating 16 bit binary fields for UUIDs.\n"
                ."Take a look at /plugins/tschallacka/dynamicpages/support/MysqlExtendedGrammar.php");
    }

    public static function tableName($table_name) {
        $prefix = DB::connection()->getTablePrefix();
        return $prefix . $table_name;
    }
    public static function getExtendedSchema() 
    {
        $stutter = new static();
        Event::fire('tschallacka.get.binary_uuid.grammars',[$stutter]);
        $driver = DB::connection()->getConfig('driver');
        $grammar = $stutter->getGrammar($driver);

        DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new $grammar());

        $schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();
        $schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
            return new ExtendedBlueprint($table, $callback);
        });

        return $schema;
    }
}
```

Then in your migration file

```
class CreatePagesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {

        $schema = Stutter::getExtendedSchema();

        $schema->create(Stutter::tableName('pagemanager_pages'), 
            function(ExtendedBlueprint $table) {
                $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
                $table->increments('id');

                $table->binary_uuid('auid');

                $table->timestamps();
                $table->string('name')->nullable();
                $table->string('slug',2048)->nullable();
                $table->boolean('active')->nullable();

            });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tschallacka_pagemanager_pages');
    }
}
```

Then in your model you can have attributes like:

```
protected function getAuidAttribute() 
{
    static $uuid;
    if(isset($this->attributes['auid'])) {
        if(is_null($uuid)) {
            $uuid = Uuid::import($this->attributes['auid']);
        }
        return $uuid->string;
    }

    return null;
}

protected function beforeCreate() 
{
    $uuid = Uuid::generate(4);
    $this->auid = $uuid->bytes;
    $this->attributes['auid'] = $uuid->bytes;
}
```

The UUID library i'm using is https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid

**notice**

I'm actually using the Octobercms framework, which might differ on some points on minor implementation details, but the majority of the stuff should still hold up for laravel, since OctoberCMS is just a layer on top of Laravel.